# What is the Income Tax treatment, if person A transfers more than fifty thousand Indian rupees electronically to Person B's saving account?

Tags: income-tax, india, bank-account

I wanted to know the income tax implications if A transfers more than fifty thousand Indian rupees to B's saving account electronically. The B is not a relative to A.
Would B be taxed as he/she is a recipient? 
And will A be questioned on the intent on transfer? 
What kind of documentation is required for A to furnish if in case there is a income tax scrutiny?

Comment: Why did A transfer R50K to B?  As a gift, loan, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Income tax is payable by B. Unless Income tax authority has reason to believe A transferred for tax evasion, they are not bothered.

This does not mean other agencies like ED or Police will be not bothered, if they have reason to believe the intent was for unlawful gains it would be investigated

Comment: Although it should be an independent question but what are the ways it can be documented so that you have right explanation to Tax authorities? Like if its is Loan, Gift.

Comment: @Sam type it on stamp paper and notarize it or get it registered